# Start transaction has no effect in nuodb

Tags: node.js, transactions, nuodb

In nuodb when I start a transaction with "start transaction" why do I need to manually set autocommit to off before?

What is the role of start transaction if it has no effect when autocommit is on?

http://doc.nuodb.com/display/v111/START+TRANSACTION

I can't do transaction using nodejs, I can submit command "start transaction" but not "autocommit off"

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in more detail here:
http://www.nuodb.com/community/showthread.php?1121-Can-t-ROLLBACK-a-TRANSACTION

From a high level, setting autocommit is not exposed outside of NuoSQL (the NuoDB CLI). That is scheduled to be addressed in the next release which is due in the next few weeks.